# why dose jsPDF pass the table like this on a PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[it generates it like this from html to pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZKdk.png)

thats my code i hope you guys can help, when ever i try to pass the table from html to pdf, its passes it like om the picture.. i need help please

this is html

```
 <html>

 <head>
     <script src="../tools/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
     <script src="../tools/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
     <input type="button" onclick="generarTabla()" value="generar tablar">
     <input type="button" onclick="generarPdf()" value="generar pdf">
     <div id="ta1">
         <div id="ta2" method="post">
             <table border="1" id="tabla" style="text-align: center;">

             </table>
         </div>
     </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

thats the javascript

```
    var col = ["numero", "operador", "indice", "igual", "resultado"];
    var row = [];

    function generarTabla() {
    var a = prompt("table of?");
    a = parseInt(a);
    var str = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $("#tabla").append("<tr><td>" + a + "</td><td>*</td><td>" + (i+1) + "</td><td>=</td><td>" + (a * (i+1)) + "</td><tr>");
    }
   }

    function generarPdf() {
    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "letter");

    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("tabla"));

    doc.autoTable(col, res.data, {
        tableWidth: "wrap",
        theme: "grid",
        showHeader: 'never',
        styles: {
            halign: "center"
        }
    });

    doc.save("text.pdf");
}
```

Comment: What is the format you want?

Comment: because your last `<tr>` should be `</tr>` ... i.e. `...</td><tr>");` => `...</td></tr>");`

Comment: that did it, how stupiiid thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX thx bro, i feel stupid now haha